# mysql-server taking too much time to be installed and generated failed

Tags: server, 15.04, mysql

I am trying to Run and Install the mysql-server on my ubuntu, it's always stating `preparing to unpack ../mysql-server-5.6_5.6.27-0ubunbu0.15.04_amd64deb ...`

in addition to the above I have a problem whenever I try to install any new service or configure the below erorr shows up, i tried everything stopping mysql service, re installing, removing, rebooting, nothing is working.

ubuntu 15.04

thank you for your help :)

in addition to that I have the following notice
[click here for first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsdcL.png)

[click here for ubuntu error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2CbC.png)

Comment: Stop `mysql` server, do `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.6_5.6.27-0ubunbu0.15.04_amd64deb` and then try..

Comment: Any reason you are trying to install mysql server this way?

Comment: which way do you mean, I have tried to remove it and then trying to reinstall it again but it's all generating the same above error

Comment: I got new error @heemay , I tried `sudo mysql stop` it gave me _ERROR 2002 (HY000), CANNOT CONNECT TO LOCAL MYSQL SERVER THROUGH SOCKET/MYSQLD/MYSQL.SOCK_, and I tried `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop` this one also failed by giving _mysql.serviceFailed to stop mysql: connection timed out, failed to get load state of mysql.service: connection time out. failed!_

Comment: Then probably `mysql` is not running..check `sudo netstat -tlpn` and then use the `rm` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not replying, but the upgrade didn't work, it always stated needed a partial upgrade which wasn't working either, and i have tried to re configure all services, and installing mysql, and phpmyadmin again but both of them has some sort of dependency on the other one. 
Long story short, nothing worked actually, whenever I try to install mysql it states no package is found.

The solution was I have restored the Server to a Previous Point (before facing the above problem ) and now everything is working just fine.

Thank God I did a backup for all files/DB before the upgrade :)

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing it using apt-get?

update

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
```

try this

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Also it looks like your installation is locked.  If it is locked do this.

```
sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock;sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: I am getting _could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open(11:Resource temporarily unavailable)_  and  _ Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?_, and the answer I guess now, since I am not able to run anything!!!

Comment: You have another program open that is in control of installing software.  Do you have the software center open or something like that?  Is another terminal session installing something?  

Try rebooting and then run this.

Comment: I have restarted the server. And tried the above command it s stating that i have some missing files related to the mysql-server-56 mm is there anyway that i can delete everythng related to mysql and reinstall it again as if it s new ?

Comment: What does "apt-cache search mysql server" output?  I edited my answer try that.

Comment: i have addded my answer to both of your questions right above @Goddard

Comment: What happens when you do? sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql\*

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: ok everything was removed, I guess, but I encountered two errors while processing phpmyadmin and mysql-server-5-6 now what ? should I reinstall the mysqlserver?

Comment: yes remove everything and just start fresh.  Generally you want to install things with apt-get not a .deb file unless that is the only option of course.

Comment: try my update and then try to install again

Comment: mmm it stuck to _Preparing to unpack ../mysql-server-5.6_5.6.27-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb ..._  same as before ... should I leave it few hours, maybe it will work ?

Comment: look and see if a window popped up in the background.

Comment: there's a notification that's popping up everyonce and while stating there's an Internal Error in the system and if it keeps going on future I should reboot the system, and it's always saying that my files list file for package mysql-server-5.6 missing, assuming package has no files currently installed

Comment: can you take a picture of your "Software Sources" by typing it in the dash.

Comment: What do you mean by software source ? Which dash am sorry but this is new to me thx

Comment: Type it into the Dash.  Hit your super key and then type "Software Sources"

Comment: Sorry "Software & Updates" then click the Other Sources tab and expand that and show a picture of the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

it's stating the below

```
libapache2-mod-auth-mysql - Apache 2 module for MySQL authentication    
libdbd-mysql - MySQL database server driver for libdbi    
libdbd-mysql-perl - Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database
libdbi-perl - Perl Database Interface (DBI)
libmysqlclient-dev - MySQL database development files
libmysqlclient18 - MySQL database client library
libmysqld-dev - MySQL embedded database development files
libreoffice-base-drivers - Database connectivity drivers for LibreOffice
mysql-client-5.6 - MySQL database client binaries
mysql-client-core-5.6 - MySQL database core client binaries
mysql-common - MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
mysql-server - MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
mysql-server-5.6 - MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
mysql-server-core-5.6 - MySQL database server binaries
php5-sqlite - SQLite module for php5
python-mysqldb - Python interface to MySQL
python-mysqldb-dbg - Python interface to MySQL (debug extension)
mythtv-database - Personal video recorder application (database)
akonadi-backend-mysql - MySQL storage backend for Akonadi
ampache - web-based audio file management system
ampache-common - web-based audio file management system common files
ampache-themes - Themes for Ampache
aolserver4-nsmysql - AOLserver 4 module: module for accessing MySQL databases
auth2db - Powerful and eye-candy IDS logger, log viewer and alert generator
cacti - web interface for graphing of monitoring systems
cl-qmynd - MySQL Native Driver for Common Lisp
collectd-core - statistics collection and monitoring daemon (core system)
conquest-common - ConQuest DICOM Server - common files
conquest-mysql - ConQuest DICOM Server - MySQL backend
coturn - TURN and STUN server for VoIP
courier-webadmin - Courier mail server - web-based administration frontend
dbf2mysql - xBase <--> MySQL
dish - diligence/distributed shell for parallel sysadmin
dovecot-mysql - secure POP3/IMAP server - MySQL support
dpm-copy-server-mysql - DPM copy server with MySQL database backend
dpm-name-server-mysql - DPM nameserver server with MySQL database backend
dpm-server-mysql - Disk Pool Manager (DPM) server with MySQL database backend
dpm-srm-server-mysql - DPM SRM server with MySQL database backend
drizzle - Server binaries for Drizzle Database
drizzle-plugin-json-server - JSON HTTP (NoSQL) interface for Drizzle
freeradius-mysql - MySQL module for FreeRADIUS server
fsgateway - FUSE module to browse database's metadata, sugar datastores and xml files
gsql-mysql-engine - MySQL engine for GSQL
ilohamail - Light weight yet full featured multilingual web-based IMAP/POP3 client
irssi-scripts - collection of scripts for irssi
jffnms - PHP Network Management System
kamailio - very fast and configurable SIP proxy
kamailio-mysql-modules - MySQL database connectivity module for Kamailio
letodms-webdav - document management system based on PHP and MySQL - WebDAV server
lfc-server-mysql - LCG File Catalog (LFC) server with MySQL database backend
libdbix-class-perl - extensible and flexible object <-> relational mapper
libdbix-introspector-perl - module to detect what database code is connected to
libdrizzle-dbg - library for the Drizzle and MySQL protocols, debug symbols
libdrizzle-dev - library for the Drizzle and MySQL protocols, development files
libdrizzle4 - library for the Drizzle and MySQL protocols
libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev-compat - MariaDB Client Library for C, compatibility symlinks
libmyodbc - the MySQL ODBC driver
libmysql-java - Java database (JDBC) driver for MySQL
libmysqld-pic - PIC version of MySQL embedded server development files
libpam-mysql - PAM module allowing authentication from a MySQL server
libsqlclient-dev - SQL client library for GNUstep (development files)
libsqlclient1.7 - SQL client library for GNUstep (runtime library)
libsqlite3-mod-impexp - SQLite3 extension module for SQL script, XML, JSON and CSV import/export
libwtdbomysql-dev - MySQL/MariaDB backend for Wt::Dbo [development]
libwtdbomysql38 - MySQL/MariaDB backend for Wt::Dbo [runtime]
mariadb-client-10.0 - MariaDB database client binaries
mariadb-client-core-10.0 - MariaDB database core client binaries
mariadb-server-10.0 - MariaDB database server binaries
mariadb-server-core-10.0 - MariaDB database core server files
mariadb-test-10.0 - MariaDB database regression test suite
mha4mysql-manager - Master High Availability Manager and Tools for MySQL, Manager Package
mha4mysql-node - Master High Availability Manager and Tools for MySQL, Node Package
monodevelop-database - Database plugin for MonoDevelop
muddleftpd - A flexible and efficient FTP daemon
mylvmbackup - quickly creating backups of MySQL server's data files
mysql-mmm-agent - Multi-Master Replication Manager for MySQL - agent daemon
mysql-mmm-common - Multi-Master Replication Manager for MySQL - common files
mysql-mmm-monitor - Multi-Master Replication Manager for MySQL - monitoring daemon
mysql-mmm-tools - Multi-Master Replication Manager for MySQL - tools
mysql-proxy - high availability, load balancing and query modification for mysql
mysql-source-5.6 - MySQL source
mysql-testsuite-5.6 - MySQL 5.6 testsuite
mysql-utilities - collection of scripts for managing MySQL servers
mysql-workbench - MySQL Workbench - a visual database modeling, administration and queuing tool
mysql-workbench-data - MySQL Workbench -- architecture independent data
mysqltcl - interface to the MySQL database for the Tcl language
mysqltuner - high-performance MySQL tuning script
mysqmail - real-time logging system in MySQL
mysqmail-courier-logger - real-time logging system in MySQL - Courier traffic-logger
mysqmail-dovecot-logger - real-time logging system in MySQL - Dovecot traffic-logger
mysqmail-postfix-logger - real-time logging system in MySQL - Postfix traffic-logger
mysqmail-pure-ftpd-logger - real-time logging system in MySQL - Pure-FTPd traffic-logger
mytop - top like query monitor for MySQL
nagios-plugins-contrib - Plugins for nagios compatible monitoring systems
nanoweb - HTTP server written in PHP
nova-console - OpenStack Compute - Console
oar-server-mysql - OAR batch scheduler MySQL server backend package
papercut - simple and extensible NNTP server
pdns-backend-mysql - generic MySQL backend for PowerDNS
pennmush-mysql - text-based multi-user virtual world server with MySQL support
percona-server-server-5.6 - Percona Server database server binaries
percona-server-test-5.6 - Percona Server database test suite
percona-toolkit - Command-line tools for MySQL and system tasks
percona-xtrabackup - Open source backup tool for InnoDB and XtraDB
percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.6 - Percona XtraDB Cluster database server binaries
perdition - POP3 and IMAP4 Proxy server
php-db - PHP PEAR Database Abstraction Layer
php5-mysqlnd-ms - MySQL replication and load balancing module for PHP
php5-pinba - Pinba module for PHP 5
phpmyadmin - MySQL web administration tool
pinba-engine-mysql-5.5 - realtime statistics server for PHP using MySQL as a read-only interface
pnopaste-cli - Pastebin with syntax highlighting (cli tool)
postfix-cluebringer-mysql - metapackage for mysql support in postfix-cluebringer
postfix-gld - greylisting daemon for postfix, written in C, uses MySQL
proftpd-mod-mysql - Versatile, virtual-hosting FTP daemon - MySQL module
pure-ftpd-mysql - Secure and efficient FTP server with MySQL user authentication
pysieved - managesieve server
python-mysql.connector - pure Python implementation of MySQL Client/Server protocol
python-os-apply-config - Creates config files out of cloud metadata
python-pysqlite2 - Python interface to SQLite 3
python3-mysql.connector - pure Python implementation of MySQL Client/Server protocol (Python3)
r-cran-rodbc - GNU R package for ODBC database access
refdb-server - Reference database and bibliography tool - sql server
rfc5766-turn-server - TURN and STUN server for VoIP
rhythmbox-ampache - play audio streams from an Ampache server
robojournal - cross-platform journal/diary tool
robojournal-doc - cross-platform journal/diary tool - documentation
root-plugin-sql-mysql - MySQL client plugin for ROOT
roundcube-mysql - metapackage providing MySQL dependencies for RoundCube
solr-common - Enterprise search server based on Lucene3 - common files
sputnik - Extensible wiki
sqlgrey - Postfix Greylisting Policy Server
sqlline - JDBC command-line utility for issuing SQL
sympa - Modern mailing list manager
sysbench - Cross-platform and multi-threaded benchmark tool
tango-db - TANGO distributed control system - database server
tarantool-mysql-plugin - Tarantool in-memory database - MySQL connector    
tsung - distributed multi-protocol load testing tool    
viewvc-query - utility to query CVS and Subversion commit database    
voms-mysql-plugin - VOMS server plugin for MySQL    
voms-mysql-plugin-dbg - VOMS server plugin for MySQL - Debug Symbols    
yate-mysql - MySQL support module for yate    
zabbix-proxy-mysql - network monitoring solution - proxy (using MySQL)    
zabbix-server-mysql - network monitoring solution - server (using MySQL)
```

Thanks
in addition to the above, the homepage is not displaying the shortcuts (firefox,home, etc.)

@Goddard, I got the below Image
[this the image result of mysql-server-*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgjqR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got the below error

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl{a} libmysqlclient18{a} mysql-client-5.6{a} mysql-client-core-5.6{a} mysql-common{a} mysql-server-core-5.6{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  phpmyadmin{a} 
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-server-5.6 
1 packages upgraded, 6 newly installed, 1 to remove and 104 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/20.7 MB of archives. After unpacking 75.3 MB will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "templatedb": /var/cache/debconf/templates.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'mysql-server-5.6' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 259040 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing phpmyadmin (4:4.2.12-2) ...
debconf: DbDriver "templatedb": /var/cache/debconf/templates.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
debconf: DbDriver "templatedb": /var/cache/debconf/templates.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
```